# covering Localization statement in blazer server app with bunit in dot net 7

Tags: .net-core, blazor-server-side, bunit

Recently we upgraded from dot net 5 to 7 Now code coverage is not fully covered
Mainly localization related code is not getting covered.

Tried adding
mockLocalizer.Setup(_ => _["Denied"]).Returns(new LocalizedString("Denied", "No Access"));
testContext.Services.AddSingleton(mockLocalizer.Object);
But nothing seem to work Not sure why this is happening the same code was 100% percent covered before upgrade to 7.0.Please help me to cover this Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLwEG.png)

Comment: It may be your coverage library that is not able to correctly detect that it is included.

Comment: Btw. A good way to mock localization is just to return the string that was passed in out again.

Comment: Could you please provide an example so i can try and see